# popup in an absolute position to be scrolled with the data-role="footer"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a footer that contains a slideing div as a menu, My purpose is that when I will scroll the page the popup will scroll with the footer and it will be shown at the same position on screen at any time.

```
<div id="placeholder">
      // the pop up will be here
</div>
<div data-role="footer id="adiv">
         <div id="slidemenu">
              <a></a>
         </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the way I understand your question, all you're really needing is the `position: fixed` css style:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Fixed_positioning

Comment: it's the right solution in a case when you won't use a popup, Because when I'm writing $('#'+activePage[0].id).page('destroy').page(); I'm having troubles, I'm writing this code to get the popup functionality and themes